# Add custom message to thrown exception while maintaining stack trace in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have a small piece of code that runs through some transactions for processing. Each transaction is marked with a transaction number, which is generated by an outside program and is not necessarily sequenced. When I catch an Exception in the processing code I am throwing it up to the main class and logging it for review later. I'd like to add the transaction number to this thrown Exception. Is it possible to do this while still maintaining the correct stack trace?

For Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        processMessage();
    }catch(Exception E){
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void processMessage() throws Exception{
    String transNbr = "";
    try{
        transNbr = "2345";
        throw new Exception();
    }catch(Exception E){
        if(!transNbr.equals("")){
            //stack trace originates from here, not from actual exception
            throw new Exception("transction: " + transNbr); 
        }else{
            //stack trace gets passed correctly but no custom message available
            throw E;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Try:

```
throw new Exception("transction: " + transNbr, E);
```

Comment: Instances are lowercase by convention in Java.

Answer (score 21):

Exceptions are usually immutable: you can't change their message after they've been created. What you can do, though, is chain exceptions:

```
throw new TransactionProblemException(transNbr, originalException);
```

The stack trace will look like

```
TransactionProblemException : transNbr
at ...
at ...
caused by OriginalException ...
at ...
at ...
```

Comment: This is nicer, since the exception class name is tied to the domain - it's immediately recognizable exactly the source of the problem. Plus code analysis tools may raise warnings when you `throw new Exception(...)`.

Comment: @vikingsteve - What is wrong with that approach ? I have selenium automation code for a web page. We expand a menu before we can select its options. I do this with 2  functions - expandMenu() & selectOptions(options). In selectOptions(...) we catch an exception "ElementNotInteractable" if the user forgot to call the expandMenu(). I want to add string to the execption to tell him exactly why it happened like "Reason - You forgot to expand the menu !". Without this message, the user will have to run the whole code again to see why the exception occurred.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Is there any major problem with this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/12568397/6648326 ? If not, then can we use it for the use case in my previous comment ?

Answer (score 11):

There is an `Exception` constructor that takes also the cause argument: [Exception(String message, Throwable t)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29).

You can use it to propagate the stacktrace:

```
try{
    //...
}catch(Exception E){
    if(!transNbr.equals("")){
        throw new Exception("transaction: " + transNbr, E); 
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use super while extending Exception

```
if (pass.length() < minPassLength)
    throw new InvalidPassException("The password provided is too short");
 } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    throw new InvalidPassException("No password provided", e);
 }


// A custom business exception
class InvalidPassException extends Exception {

InvalidPassException() {

}

InvalidPassException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
InvalidPassException(String message, Throwable cause) {
   super(message, cause);
}
```

}

}

[source](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/create-custom-exception-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Exception class extend from Exception and add attribute just like that:`
public class PaymentException extends Exception {
public Object data;

```
public PaymentException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
}

public void setData(Object o) {
    data = o;
}
public Object getData() {
    return data;
}
```

}`

Answer (score -1):

You can use your exception message by:-

```
 public class MyNullPointException extends NullPointerException {

        private ExceptionCodes exceptionCodesCode;

        public MyNullPointException(ExceptionCodes code) {
            this.exceptionCodesCode=code;
        }
        @Override
        public String getMessage() {
            return exceptionCodesCode.getCode();
        }


   public class enum ExceptionCodes {
    COULD_NOT_SAVE_RECORD ("cityId:001(could.not.save.record)"),
    NULL_POINT_EXCEPTION_RECORD ("cityId:002(null.point.exception.record)"),
    COULD_NOT_DELETE_RECORD ("cityId:003(could.not.delete.record)");

    private String code;

    private ExceptionCodes(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following code is a simple example that worked for me.Let me call the function `main` as parent function and `divide` as child function.
Basically i am *throwing a new exception with **my custom message*** (for the parent's call) if an exception occurs in child function by *catching the Exception in the child first.*

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            long ans=divide(0);
            System.out.println("answer="+ans);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("got exception:"+e.getMessage());

        }

    }
    public static long divide(int num) throws Exception{
        long x=-1;
        try {
            x=5/num;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception("Error occured in divide for number:"+num+"Error:"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

the last line `return x` will not run if error occurs somewhere in between.