# How to change message on Hibernate's ConstraintViolationException?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When I am saving entity that violates any database constraint I get massage as below.

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

How can I internationalize this kind of messages? Can I set different message for each property separately?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568340/add-custom-message-to-thrown-exception-while-maintaining-stack-trace-in-java Is this doing the trick ?

Comment: I would need to change Hibernate souroce code, I dont want to do this.

Comment: if something originates in Hibernate source code and you want to change it, then you either change Hibernate source code, or you catch and rethrow the exception with whatever changed ...