# Rethrow Exception Real Application

Tags: java, exception, java-7

In Java 7 Rethrow Exception feature added.I know it's concept but I want to see the real application of it and why this feature needed?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Rethrowing Exceptions with More Inclusive Type Checking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)  feature

> in Java SE 7, you can specify the exception types FirstException and SecondException in the throws clause in the rethrowException method declaration

When you want to declare **specific** exceptions that can be thrown (mainly when you are catching a generic error)

For example see [Precise Rethrow example](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-7-precise-rethrow.html):

> ```
> public static void precise() throws ParseException, IOException{
>     try {
>         new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse("foo");
>         new FileReader("file.txt").read();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
>         throw e;
>     }
> }
> ```

This also make your code compliant to Sonar's [Raw Exception rule](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/test/files/checks/RawException.java).

Note you can similarly catch `Throwable`

Answer (score 2):

I will take examples from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) 
This is the example:

```
  static class FirstException extends Exception { }
  static class SecondException extends Exception { }

  public void rethrowException(String exceptionName) throws FirstException, SecondException {
    try {
      if (exceptionName.equals("First")) {
        throw new FirstException();
      } else {
        throw new SecondException();
      }
    } catch (FirstException e) {
      throw e;
    }catch (SecondException e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

This compiles with both java 6 an 7.

If you want to keep checked exceptions from method signature, you have to keep cumbersome catch clauses in java 6.

In Java 7 you can do it in following way:

```
public void rethrowException(String exceptionName) throws FirstException, SecondException {
  try {
    if (exceptionName.equals("First")) {
      throw new FirstException();
    } else {
      throw new SecondException();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

So your benefit is that you have less cumbersome catch clause.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of use-cases:

1. Using rethrow, you can **edit the stacktrace information** to make
   it more accurate. Also when needed you can hide or rid off the
   unnecessary internal details in stack trace.

   ```
   try     { //... }
   catch (Exception e) { throw (Exception) e.fillInStackTrace(); }
   ```

   Real application of `fillInStackTrace` is very well explained here:
   [Why is Throwable.fillInStackTrace() method public? Why would someone use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9788993/1465553)

   Quote from the book "Thinking in Java" written by Bruce Eckel:

   > If you want to install new stack trace information, you can do so by
   >   calling `fillInStackTrace( )`, which returns a Throwable object that it
   >   creates by stuffing the current stack information into the old
   >   exception object
2. Add custom message to the thrown exception. [Add custom message to thrown exception while maintaining stack trace in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568340/add-custom-message-to-thrown-exception-while-maintaining-stack-trace-in-java)

A simple example I can think of:

```
void fileOperator(String operationType) throws Exception(){ ... }

void fileReader() throws Exception {
    try{
        fileOperator('r');
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw Exception("Failed to read the file", e);
    }
}

void fileWriter() throws Exception{
    try{
        fileOperator('w');
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw Exception("Failed to write the file", e);
    }
}
```

Also, we can throw a more specific exception type (say FileReadException, FileWriteException) from the `catch` block.