# How to differ same exception type in JPA

Tags: spring, jpa

When you try to insert a duplicate entity a DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown by JPA . If you have too many data in your field(e.g. field has 1023 chars but you would enter 2000) there is also a DataIntegrityViolationException thrown. Of course I want to present an appropriate error message to the user , so what is the best way to differentiate the 2 errors while the same Exception is thrown.

One way I figured out to somehow parse the message inside the exception. But what if this gets updated...   Another would be to check this always on the client.

Comment: You dont.  You validate the data before going to the database.

Comment: so you think I should rather always check it in the browser on client side ?

Comment: You validate requests on the server and return suitable reponse if validation fails. https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

Comment: You need to read more about Try and Catch. Also this will help too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568340/add-custom-message-to-thrown-exception-while-maintaining-stack-trace-in-java. Also if you using some form(s) etc, its your responsibility to restrict user to do such obvious mistakes.